# (jQuery) Issue with fading in/out elements within .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, fadein, fadeout

I'm having an issue trying to get `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()`, and `.hide()` to behave properly when an element is hovered over.

Let's say I have a container, `.post-box`.

`.post-box` contains two divs: `.description` and `.quote`. The `.quote` div is initially hidden so that when `.post-box` is hovered over, it fades in and takes the place of the `.description` div, which gets hidden with `.hide()`.

When `.post-box` is hovered out of, `.quote` fades out and `.description` is faded in again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var description = $('.description');
    var quote = $('.quote');
    var postBox = $('.post-box');

    postBox.hover(function() {
        $(this).find(description).clearQueue().stop(true, true).hide(0, function() {
            quote.fadeIn(300);
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(quote).clearQueue().stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function() {
            description.fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
});
```

It seems that I've got this concept working fairly well except for one issue. If you quickly hover over `.post-box`, quickly hover out, and then quickly hover over again, you're presented with both the `.quote` and `.description` divs showing at the same time [(see example screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udICt.png).

I thought I was preventing them from firing at the same time based on how my functions are set up, but I must be missing something important for this to be happening.

[**Here is my fiddle so you can see it in action.**](https://jsfiddle.net/8r0xpt61/3/)

Could somebody please lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be to also clear the animation queue for the quote element on hover.

```
$(this).find(quote).clearQueue().stop(true, true).hide();
```

[I've updated the fiddle accordingly](https://jsfiddle.net/1eq3bqet/1/) .

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Thank you very, very much!! :)